# Spring Cloud AWS: optional cache manager

Tags: caching, spring-cloud, amazon-elasticache

Spring cache configuration allows to fall back to no cache using `CompositeCacheManager` with `fallbackToNoOpCache` property set to true. How could this be used with spring-cloud-aws cache manager so that, when a non-existing cache cluster is specified, the composite cache manager falls back to no cache? With an example configuration like this:

```
<aws-cache:cache-manager>
    <aws-cache:cache-cluster name="CacheCluster" />
</aws-cache:cache-manager>
```

the application just won't start when there's no cluster named `CacheCluster` configured. When a `CompositeCacheManager` is configured like this:

```
<aws-cache:cache-manager id="elasticacheManager">
    <aws-cache:cache-cluster name="CacheCluster" />
</aws-cache:cache-manager>

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.CompositeCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManagers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="elasticacheManager" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="fallbackToNoOpCache" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

with a non-existing cache *CacheCluster*, then the application fails to start up complaining: "No bean named 'elasticacheManager' is defined".
Is there a way to create an AWS cache manager programmatically and use something like a FactoryBean for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Spring Cloud AWS does not support the configuration of a fallback cache. I will add it to our backlog as a feature request. In the meantime you could use the same workaround I did in the reference application using spring profiles (see [ReferenceApplication.java](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/aws-refapp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/sample/ReferenceApplication.java#L68)).

Comment: I checked the implementation of CacheBeanDefinitionParser and found out that it creates a SimpleCacheManager, and it's not easy to hook into the factory. Even if it's possible to use something like BeanFactoryPostProcessor to check cache cluster availability and remove caches that are unavailable, the overhead of implementing this is higher than using a different solution, without spring cloud for now.
Unfortunately the trick with profiles doesn't work in my case: in fact, it is intended to be used in production environment to provide fail-safe behavior when cache cluster is unavailable.